Login freeze up
Again I am trying to resolve this issue. I am on KDE Plasma. When I boot up, the login page sometimes freezes with me not being able to input my password. It is X11. Is there any remedy for this?

You've not provided any Ubuntu release details which is the starting point for providing help (release details lets us know what software stack you're using, ie. what software & versions are involved).  You mention greeter or the login prompt; which occurs before any X11/Wayland session is started, yet mention X11 which implies you had logged in; is this correct? as you say login page which is before X11/Xorg even starts (until you login it doesn't know what session to start up)

Hello. Thanks for replying. I am using Ubuntu studio 22.04. Sometimes the login page doesnt allow input. A previous guy asked me if I am using wayland or x11. It's x11. It only happens sometimes.

You might be hit by this bug.
I had the same issue in Ubuntu Studio 22.04. I cannot find exactly where I got this from, but apparently it happens when the boot is too fast, so anything delaying the bootup is kind of a workaround. See also a related question here.
Usually the time I spend entering the decryption password for my home partition during boot is sufficient, so I did not mess with the configuration files, but it might help you.

Thanks. I will try this.

Read through those threads. Some pretty nerdy stuff being talked about. A little over my head. No definitive fix or instructions provided. Still at a loss as to how to resolve this.
